# How to Connect a Script with Triggers and Functions to Multiple Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a standalone script with the following code:

```
var key = "ID of the Sheet";

function createTriggers() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('filter')
      .forSpreadsheet(key)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function filter(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key);
// rest of the function below
}
```

This has 3 parts - The key of the Google spreadsheet the script is connected to, the trigger creation function of the spreadsheet and the function.

I need this script to be connected to multiple sheets. As of now, I am creating individual standalone script for each sheet.

How to have multiple sheets connected to the same standalone script when the code is in the above format?

If we cannot have multiple sheets connected to this script, is there any other way that's better than creating a standalone scripts for each and every sheet?

Comment: Thanks! With this, I won't have to create separate functions. But I will have to create separate trigger for each spreadsheet, right?

Comment: and time driven functions won't work with this method, right?

Comment: can you share an example code of how to loop through keys for creating the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a [restriction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) for creating triggers

> A script is bound to a Google Sheets, Docs, or Forms file if it was created from that document rather than as a standalone script.

You could save your script as standalone service with `doGet` or `doPost` function. And make requests to it from your spreadsheets by their own scripts on trigger.

Comment: I don't want to have any code in the sheet, as it's shared with users who have edit access and they might modify the code. I need this to be done via standalone scripts only or any other way in which we don't have to save the code in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @dc09 I got your point. Well.. may be you should create an [Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons) that would be added to each spreadsheet.. but again - as far as I know editors can them from document =)