# Programmatically creating triggers in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making (or attempting to make) a script that sends out a Details Spreadsheet to new customers. The idea is, to combat the rising tide of people entering their details incorrectly, we could just share with them a spreadsheet like this:

[Team Details Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulXgj.jpg)

Then, if each Details Spreadsheet had a script attached, every time someone changed their details, it could be automatically copied into our database (another Google Sheet on our drive).

I figured the easiest way to do that was to make a Template to copy and re-name for each new customer. It also means any script needed by the Details Spreadsheet would be copied from the Template (I made one called copyDetails). Easy peasy! Except then I needed to build one onEdit trigger programmatically and, for the life of me I cannot figure out whether it's not possible or I'm just doing it wrong.

So my first port of call was, of course, [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). In it, it has an example and the helpful line "To create this trigger from a standalone script, simply replace SpreadsheetApp.getActive() with a call to SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)"

So I tried that. I had this script:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Ay2f9wnsc8p7_eJIn6Hov0XN4Y_mArm5");
var NewSheetID = DriveApp.getFileById("1X6zFGFoa4C4WvrdNOodbME9vY92lo_oPARUkX7Vfskk").makeCopy(AppNum + ' Details', folder).getId();
Logger.log(NewSheetID);

ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyDetails").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.openById(NewSheetID)).onEdit().create();
```

I ran the script and there's no triggers present on the new Spreadsheet. But on the project that ran the script there's now a trigger for copyDetails! That's 50% success. By why was it on source sheet, not the target sheet? So I had a deeper look, and apparently forSpreadsheet() should have the target sheet's ID, not 'openById'. Okay, so I changed the last line to:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyDetails").forSpreadsheet(NewSheetID).onEdit().create();
```

Still no dice. Same result. So I went to copy the example exactly, notes and all, and I realised it needed the target sheet to be the Active Sheet. So, okay:

1. Added new line to make NewSheetID the Active Sheet
2. Copied the example script exactly into my script.

Still got the exact same result. At this point I'm thinking it's set up by Google to work this way. No matter what Sheet ID you put in, it makes the trigger in the project that ran the script. But that seems a little silly. Why bother with something so limited?

So that's where I'm at right now. I guess my questions are:

1. Did I just screw it up? I'd say I'm an enthusiast-level programmer only, and it's totally possible I just put something in wrong.
2. If I didn't screw up, but that is in fact the way that works, is there a way to set up an onEdit trigger to copied files from within a script?

I thought about adding an onOpen trigger to the Template, and in that function checking ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() to see if a trigger had been set up for copyDetails(), then setting one up if there was none. But that apparently doesn't have the required permission to do that. You'd need an installable trigger to check ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers(), and we're back where we started. I could skip checking ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers(), but I don't like the idea of setting up a new onEdit trigger every time someone opens the file - I feel like that would result in heaps and heaps of needless triggers.

Sorry for the mammoth post, but I feel like more detail is preferable to less. I'm just all out of ideas at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a "bounded" script? You might want to try it through a script that is not bounded to a particular spreadsheet as the documentation states `To create this trigger from a standalone script`. Just a thought, not sure if this will solve your issue.

Comment: ... so, I feel stupid. I did not realise you could have **un**-bound scripts. This presents a possible solution!!

The order information (customer's email, number of tickets, etc, etc) *is* plopped into a spreadsheet, so a bound script would make sense. But as that's not working, is it possible to call an un-bound script from within a bound one? 

Like, if I had an un-bound script that just made the triggers (let's say I called it makeTriggers), can I have a line in my bound script that goes "makeTriggers(NewSheetID);" (passing it the ID number of the newly made sheet would be amazing)?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation regarding libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Comment: So I've been playing around with libraries and I discovered that the standalone script also has *exactly* the same problem. I've got a Distribution script that makes the Details forms, the Details script that I want the trigger on, and now the Standalone script. If I run the standalone from the library (just hitting the triangle play button), it will build the trigger on the Standalone script. If I call the library function from within the Distribution script, it will build it on the Distribution script. There's no way I can get it to build the trigger on the Details script

Comment: Okay, so, actually, Casper you have answered my initial question. I now have a new question about making standalone scripts do the install Trigger thing. I can't mark your comment as answered (maybe I don't have enough reputation?), but I'm going to close this and ask a new question :)

Thank you so much for pointing me towards libraries!

Comment: Comments cannot be marked as accepted answer. Perhaps you can provide the answer by yourself as just a stand alone script did not seem to solve the issue? Other people might benefit if you can provide a description of how you'd got it to work. Happy to hear the libraries helped you further along!

Comment: Have you thought about a Google Form to collect data instead of a Google Sheet? You can bound scripts to them as well.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203689/how-to-connect-a-script-with-triggers-and-functions-to-multiple-google-sheets)?

Comment: Thanks @Diego. I hadn't, but I think I've discovered what was wrong in my plan. Sharing it with people and subsequent authorisations are more the problem here then any actual coding. But I will take a look at forms. I hadn't realised you could bind scripts to them as well. I'll investigate and report back

Comment: Hi @McBestington, have you succeeded to resolve the issue? Have the same one and can't wrap my head around it